# Codeigniter Routes Controller Sub Folder

Tags: codeigniter, controller, routes

I've a problem with routes and controller. I've got 2 types of controller: first type is used to manage the webpages, second type is used for cms and I prefer to put them in a sub-folder. Example:

```
/controller/site.php (for webpages)
/controller/admin/ (for controllers to manage cms)
```

in routes.php I've write:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "site/$1";
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/$1";
```

I've got the file .htacces set in this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|js|font|woff|ttf|svg|eot|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and this variable on config.php:

```
$config['index'] = '';
```

but it works only for "site". If I write "mywebsite/admin/login" for example, it return 404 error.

I've found also MY_Router to extend CI_Route but doesn't work.

Can someone help me to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put the `admin` route before the `any` route:

```
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "site/$1";
```

otherwise it will always hit `any` and redirect to `site`. You have to give it a chance to match `admin` before matching `any`.

Comment: THANKS A LOT! I've solved the problem! I didn't think that changing the order would have create so many troubles. Thanks again!