# Htaccess doesn't allow requesting resources in sub folder application

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, codeigniter, wamp

I'm having problem with configuration of my .htaccess file. Application is written in AngularJs, while restApi application is written in Codeigniter and it's located in /server folder.

This is my folder structure
[image]
My api folder structure
[image]

This is my .htaccess file on which i'm working on

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The problem is that when ever i try to access my api resource i'm keep getting 404 page, while this works perfectly on my debian nginx server, that's why i'm guessing that this is the problem in .htaccess file

```
http://myApp.com/server/api/products/latest/1
```

[image]

I hope you guys can help me. If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can I see how the server controller looks like?

Comment: Would you like to see folder structure or some specific server controller? Other wise, this works fine on centos 7 + nginx, debian + nginx.. It just have problems when i try to add it on my localhost wamp setup.

Comment: No, your URL indicated http://myApp.com/server/api/products/latest/1, if this is CodeIgniter,  my assumption is, server is a controller (http://myApp.com/server)

Comment: not entirely true. This application has same folder structure as mine and its working. problem here is in htaccess file. 
https://github.com/colinjlacy/clocks

Comment: then you can call application resources with angular this way:
server/projects/insert... folder/controller/function or folder/folder/controller/function/argument... this can be achieved with proper nginx location configuration, but i don't know how to do this with .htaccess

Comment: I see. Could this be a routing issue (not sure)? check out this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765439/codeigniter-routes-controller-sub-folder

Comment: no it's not this. Current problem is that server doesn't resolve request properly because of miss configuration of .htaccess file. 404 means it doesn't find /server/index.php

Comment: Try in .htaccess RewriteBase /server/. Also make sure that in config $config['index_page'] = ' ';

Comment: @pr0metheus please post an answer so i can accept it as correct! Tahnk you mate

Comment: @Valor_ No problem.I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /server/
```

Also make sure that in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = ' ';
```